# Apache2 connection pooling

Tags: apache2, connection, pooling

I want to implement apache **connection pooling between two apache2 servers.** So that there are connections already established and my response time is reduced.

I am aware that we need to use either Worker or Event MPM. I also need to know how to identify the same in log files.

Thanks in advance,
Paresh

Comment: should be a serverfault.com question.

Comment: i am new to this what has to be done ?

Comment: ask in serverfault.com or wait for this question to be transferred to there.